# Formatear el resultado de response.css de scrapy spider

Tags: python, django, scrapy

Cuando ejecuto mi `spider` el valor que deseo obtener los guardo en un diccionario, pero quiero también crear una carpeta con el nombre de uno de los resultados

```
def parse(self, response):

    ml_item = ScrapyItem()
    mt_item = ScrapyItem()

    mt_item['title'] = response.css('div.info h1::text').extract()
    mt_item['Parodies'] = response.css('span.characters 

    name = str(mt_item['title'])
    os.mkdir(name)
```

El problema es que se guarda como `[u"Winter's Tale"]`.

¿ Cómo puedo formatearlo sacar solo las palabras ?

Comment: Cuando usas [tag:scrapy] te devuelve una lista porque puede encontrar más de un elemento. Si sabes que solo te va a devolver un *item* estráelo con *indexing*, `lista[0]`, si te devuelve varios y quieres una carpeta de cada uno de ellos usa un for, `for item in lista:...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te adjunto una rutina que uso en estos casos, funciona con cadenas unicode y limpia varios caracteres no compatibles con los sistemas de archivo.

```
import re

from unicodedata import normalize

_punct_re = re.compile(r'[\t !"#$%&\'()*\-/<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|},.:]+')

def normalize_filename(text, delim='-'):
    """Normaliza una cadena para ser usada como nombre de archivo.

    Args:
        text (str): String a normalizar
        delim (str): Caracter de reemplazo de aquellos no vÃ¡lidos

    Ejemplo:
        >>> normalize_filename(u"Esto, no es vÃ¡lido como nombre de Archivo!", "-")
        'esto-no-es-valido-como-nombre-de-archivo'
    """
    result = []
    for word in _punct_re.split(text.lower()):
        word = normalize('NFKD', word).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        word = word.decode('utf-8')
        if word:
            result.append(word)
    return delim.join(result)
```

En `_punct_re` definimos la expresión regular de los caracteres que vamos a limpiar, que en realidad se consideran separadores y los terminamos completando con el valor del parámetro `delim`

Ejemplo:

```
print(normalize_filename(u"Esto, no es vÃ¡lido como nombre de Archivo!", "-"))
print(normalize_filename("Tampoco?funionaría esto? eh!!!!", "-"))
```

La salida:

```
esto-no-es-valido-como-nombre-de-archivo
tampoco-funionaria-esto-eh
```