# Cambiar nombre file descargado a través de url Selenium

Tags: python, excel, url, selenium

Tengo la siguiente url que por default me descarga un archivo de excel con el nombre Ad tag download.xlsx. QUiero cambiarle el nombre por otro como archivo_martin.xlsx. Se podra? Uso python 2.7 y Selenium

```
url = "https://onevideo.aol.com/inventory_sources/get_adtag_urls_export?secure=0&ft=EXCEL&piggyback_type=ANY&id={}&at=MOBILE_WEB&_sid=60c7302b-9ede-4308-93f6-014975706aff"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martín, puedes usar [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.rename) de la siguiente manera:

```
import os

os.rename("Ad tag download.xlsx", "archivo_martin.xlsx")
```

Eventualmente debes indicar el path completo al archivo si el mismo no estuviera en la carpeta desde dónde ejecutas el script.

Comment: pude hacerlo, lo unico que necesito es poder saltar un caracter de mi dic que no me permite colocarlo en el nombre del file. mi nombre es "media | " y necesito saltar la | para que pueda guardarlo. Se te ocurre de alguna forma??

Comment: @MartinBouhier, en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80957/formatear-el-resultado-de-response-css-de-scrapy-spider/81143#81143, escribí una función que "normaliza" los nombres de archivo para evitar caracteres no compatibles, revisa si te sirve.